# Не получается создать отдельный метод для soap запроса и вызвать его в тесте

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Пытаюсь вынести отдельно soap команды  чтобы создать общий набор команд (с использованием библиотек suds) которые я могу вызвать и при необходимости передать параметры для запроса в тесте через pytest

```
from test_NBI.DATA_nbi import *
from suds.client import Client
from suds.wsse import *


class NbiCommands():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def wsse(self):
        self.client = Client(WSDL_NBI)
        self.security = Security()
        self.token = UsernameToken(LOGIN, PASSWORD)
        self.security.tokens.append(self.token)
        self.client.set_options(wsse=self.security)
        return self.client

    def soap_request(self, method, **params):
        response = self.client[method](**params)
        return response

    def GetVetsion():
        r = NbiCommands.soap_request("GetVetsion")


def test_1():
    response = NbiCommands.GetVetsion()
    print(response)
```

и получаю следующую ошибку

```
    def GetVetsion():
>       r = NbiCommands.soap_request("GetVetsion")
E       TypeError: NbiCommands.soap_request() missing 1 required positional argument: 'method'
```

Если из функции GetVetsion убрать "GetVetsion" я получу ошибку о том что пропущено 2 аргумента, self и method

я ожидаю что тест будет выглядеть примерно следующим образом

```
def test_1():
    response = NbiCommands.soap_request("GetVetsion", **params)
    print(response)
```

Я буду признателен любой помощи, т.к. я уже испробовал разные варианты которые я знаю и умею, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`soap_request` это метод экземпляра, а не класса, поэтому вызывать его нужно у предварительно созданного экземпляра класса:

```
nbi = NbiCommands()
response = nbi.soap_request("GetVersion", param1='val1', param2='val2')
```

Только, чтоб работало именно так, сначала нужно сделать, чтоб `self.client` проинициализировался, можно это сделать в конструкторе:

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.wsse()
```

Ну или явно вызывать (что менее удобно):

```
nbi = NbiCommands()
nbi.wsse()
response = nbi.soap_request("GetVersion", param1='val1', param2='val2')
```

А уж если это `pytest`, то удобнее всего сделать эту зависимость теста с помощью [fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html):

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def nbi():
  return NbiCommands()


def test_1(nbi):
    response = nbi.GetVersion(param1='val1', param2='val2')
    print(response)
```

`pytest` сам создаст фикстуру перед вызовом тестового метода.

Определение `NbiCommands` как и фикстуры в таком случае имеет смысл положить в файл `conftest.py`. фикстуры из него подтягиваются автоматически.

Comment: Роман, спасибо за подробный ответ, очень помог мне в моем горе!)